# How can I get all roads/ways from an osm2pgsql shema?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap

I'm trying to create a list of every road in Germany (With latitude,longitude and Streetname).

So far I have imported the german osm file with the help of osm2pgsql into a postgres Database.

So what I am looking for is a query that allows me to query every road.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I would suggest using the `psql` tool.  So assuming your database is called gis enter the following command at the terminal:

```
psql gis
```

from within the psql tool you can query the database but first it is a g0od idea to get an idea of which tables were created by osm2psql, do this be entering:

```
\d
```

this should give you output like this:

```
               List of relations
 Schema |        Name        | Type  |  Owner   
--------+--------------------+-------+----------
 public | geography_columns  | view  | postgres
 public | geometry_columns   | table | gis
 public | planet_osm_line    | table | user
 public | planet_osm_nodes   | table | user
 public | planet_osm_point   | table | user
 public | planet_osm_polygon | table | user
 public | planet_osm_rels    | table | user
 public | planet_osm_roads   | table | user
 public | planet_osm_ways    | table | user
 public | spatial_ref_sys    | table | gis
(10 rows)
```

There we can see a likely looking candidate in planet_osm_roads, enter:

`\d planet_osm_roads`

this will show you the structure of the roads table, which will look something like this:

```
     Table "public.planet_osm_roads"
       Column       |   Type   | Modifiers 
--------------------+----------+-----------
 osm_id             | bigint   | 
 access             | text     | 
 addr:housename     | text     | 
 addr:housenumber   | text     | 
 addr:interpolation | text     | 
 admin_level        | text     | 
 aerialway          | text     | 
 aeroway            | text     | 
 amenity            | text     | 
 ....
 waterway           | text     | 
 wetland            | text     | 
 width              | text     | 
 wood               | text     | 
 z_order            | integer  | 
 way_area           | real     | 
 way                | geometry |
```

From there we can formulate our query. Something like:

```
SELECT osm_id,name,way FROM planet_osm_roads LIMIT 1;
```

will get you the first road in the list.  The documentation at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/ will help you with decoding the way geometry string.